# delete MyClass *Array[10]

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

I got really stuck trying to deallocate memory using delete without it being in a for loop.

```
    MyClass *Array[10];

cout << "Step 1 - Allocation" << endl << endl;
Array[0] = new MyClass();
Array[1] = new MyClass();
Array[2] = new MyClass(2, 4.6);
Array[3] = new MyClass(*Array[2]);
Array[4] = new MyClass();
Array[5] = new MyClass(13, 66.6);
Array[6] = new MyClass(75, 9.43);
Array[7] = new MyClass(*Array[6]);
Array[8] = new MyClass(*Array[1]);
Array[9] = new MyClass(*Array[3]);

cout << endl << "Step 2 - Write" << endl << endl;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    Array[i]->write();
    cout << endl;
}

cout << endl << "Step 3 - Deallocation" << endl << endl;
```

I tried delete[] Array, but it doesn't work.

The code must stay as it is as it's correct by what is asked to do. The only thing is to add a delete (single-lined and not a for loop) to delete Array.

Comment: What you mean by 'it doesn't work?'???...

Comment: I compile but it drops error at that point

Comment: for loop will be what you need to get rid of the objects you allocated into your bare pointer array, as the fixed array of bare pointers all point to memory you allocated.

You could try using smart pointers to manage the objects you allocate, so they will be cleaned up (deleted) when the array goes out of scope.

Comment: @user1415587: Always show the full text of the errors, because otherwise we can't really help you.

Comment: I'm compelled to recommend a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: So if there is no way to use a single line delete to delete the objects I will use the for loop as I know. It is just that the exersise asks to use a single lined delete to deallocate instead of a for loop.

Comment: @user1415587 in that case, you probably wanted a array of `MyClass` _objects_ instead of an array of `MyClass` pointers.  _That_ could be cleaned in one line.

Comment: `std::for_each(std::begin(Array), std::end(Array), std::default_delete<MyClass>());`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to delete each object that you've created using `new`:

```
for (unsigned i(0); i < 10; ++i)
    delete Array[i];
```

`Array` itself is a local variable; you did not use `new` to create it, so you do not use `delete` to destroy it.  It will be destroyed when it goes out of scope.

To address the updated constraint that the deletion must be done "single-lined and not a for loop," one could, I suppose, write:

```
delete Array[0]; delete Array[1]; delete Array[2]; delete Array[3]; delete Array[4]; delete Array[5]; delete Array[6]; delete Array[7]; delete Array[8]; delete Array[9];
```

This is a single line of code and uses no loops.  It is not possible to use a single `delete` expression to destroy what are ten effectively unrelated objects.

---

But do not do this.  Really.  Manual resource management is dangerous and very difficult to do correctly.  C++ has automatic resource management capabilities and you should use them.  In this case, it would be far better to use a `std::vector<MyClass>`:

```
std::vector<MyClass> Array;
Array.push_back(MyClass());
Array.push_back(MyClass());
Array.push_back(MyClass(2, 4.6));
Array.push_back(MyClass(Array[2]));
// Etc.
```

There's no `new` in this example, thus no `delete` is required.  The `std::vector` will clean everything up when it is destroyed.

Comment: If you're really lucky, you can do `Array.emplace_back(2, 4.6);`

Comment: The code must stay as it is. The only problem I have is that I need to use delete as a single lined command to delete the Array. Deleting it in a for loop is a piece of cake, but I got stuck trying to do it in a single line. I tried delete[] Array but it doesnt work (debugs ok but at execution it breaks).

Comment: @DeadMG oops, sorry for the tag, I edited the question and added some info

Comment: Thanks, I will use the for loop and contact tommorow my teacher to ask what was the case and if there was an error in exersise.

Comment: @DeadMG:  This isn't reddit; there is no reason to berate people here in the comments, especially someone about whom you know very little, and who is not present to defend himself.

Answer (score 6):

Operator `delete[]` must be used in conjunction with operator `new[]`, which you haven't used here.
You *manually* `new`'ed every single instance of `MyClass`.
You have to *manually* `delete` every single instance of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 5):

`delete[]` is used to delete something that was allocated by `new[]`, it does not call `delete` for each of the elements of an array. You have to call `delete` on each of your array elements within a loop.

Comment: The problem is that my exersise asks that I don't use a for loop to delete them.

Comment: @user1415587: In that case, use 10 `delete` statements.

Answer (score 4):

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>> Array;
Array.resize(10);
```

No delete required.

Comment: Don't use a unique_ptr. Use a shared_ptr. Less prone to losing your managed resource when accessing the vector contents.

Comment: @StarPilot: Don't use `shared_ptr` unless ownership is shared (which is virtually never).  Use `unique_ptr` almost always.  Maybe you're thinking of `auto_ptr`?

Comment: vector has a constructor that takes a size argument.  It suffices to just say - 'std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyClass>> Array(10);'

Answer (score 0):

> I got really stuck trying to deallocate memory using delete without it being in a for loop.

If you don't allocate memory manually, you don't need to deallocate memory manually.

```
    MyClass Array[10] = {
        MyClass(),
        MyClass(),
        MyClass(2, 4.6),
        MyClass(Array[2]),
        MyClass(),
        MyClass(13, 66.6),
        MyClass(75, 9.43),
        MyClass(Array[6]),
        MyClass(Array[1]),
        MyClass(Array[3])
    };

    // there's nothing to delete now
```

`new` or `delete` are advanced C++ features that have some niche uses. Don't use them if you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a deleter functor such as [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6485/A-Functor-that-deletes-Pointers-from-STL-Sequence) and do something like:

```
for_each(Array.begin(), Array.end(), free_ptr<C>());
```

Comment: `begin(Array)` and `end(Array)`.  `Array` is an array; it has no member functions.

Comment: Right. I copied the code sample from the article where a vector was used :)

Answer (score -1):

The only way I can see cleanup in one line is if you rewrite it so that Array is a pointer to an array of objects, instead of being a array of pointers.

```
MyClass *Array = nullptr;

cout << "Step 1 - Allocation" << endl << endl;
Array = new MyClass[10];
Array[0] = MyClass(); //removed "new"
...

cout << endl << "Step 2 - Write" << endl << endl;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    Array[i].write(); //Objects aren't pointers anymore
    cout << endl;
}

cout << endl << "Step 3 - Deallocation" << endl << endl;
delete[] MyClass;
```

Comment: new must not be removed, in fact nothing must be removed. Maybe it is a mistake from the teacher and I should use a for loop instead.

Comment: @Tr3LoS: If you can't use a loop, and can't change the type of `Array`, then either (A) The teacher is wrong, or (B) There was miscommunication between you and the teacher.